# How to change the value of an href attribute with JS?

Tags: javascript, django, dom, dom-events

I want to change the value of the href attributes of the anchor tags on my website when the user clicks a button. In particular I want to change the value of a GET parameter in this URL. (If you are not familiar with the {`% url 'select_question' %}` and {`{ subcategory.name }}` tags just ignore them they are Django template tags.) The text on the button changes but the url in the href doesn't. Mode is always "unsolved". What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
<button id="changeModeBtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="button" onclick="change()">Unsolved Questions</button>

<a class="question_link" href="{% url 'select_question' %}?subcategory={{ subcategory.slug }}&mode=unsolved">{{ subcategory.name }}</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function change(){
    var btn = document.getElementById("changeModeBtn");
    var link = document.getElementsByClassName("question_link");
    if (btn.textContent=="Unsolved Questions") {
        btn.textContent="Solved Questions";
        link.setAttribute("href", "{% url 'select_question' %}?subcategory={{ subcategory.slug }}&mode=solved");
    } else if (btn.textContent=="Solved Questions") {
        btn.textContent="All Questions";
        link.setAttribute("href", "{% url 'select_question' %}?subcategory={{ subcategory.slug }}&mode=all");
    } else {
        btn.textContent="Unsolved Questions";
        link.setAttribute("href", "{% url 'select_question' %}?subcategory={{ subcategory.slug }}&mode=unsolved");
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` return `HTMLCollection`, not single element. So change code to:

```
function change(){
    ...
    var link = document.getElementsByClassName("question_link")[0];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware about Django template tag, but if you want to set href with js on some action then you can try below solution.

```
var a = document.getElementById('yourlinkId'); 
a.href = "somelink url";
```